# Turn column with datetime values into a column for each week

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that looks like

```
color  |  date      | sales
green  | 2018-04-19 |   6
red    | 2018-12-01 |   3
blue   | 2018-09-14 |   7
 .     |     .      |   .
 .     |     .      |   .
```

Where all the dates are between 2018-01-01 and 2019-01-01 and there are many colors in the colors column that are repeated many times. For example Red could show up on various dates and Green could as well, and they can have sales on the same dates. There are several thousand records and a few other columns that aren't relevant to this query.

I have this in a dataframe and have sorted by the `date` column in ascending order and reset the index. What I would like to do, however, is make a column for each week, where each row is a unique color and the sum of the color's sales during that week.

I thought something like `df_sales['date'].resample('W').sum()` and then pivoting the data might do the trick, but that doesn't work. I know that in order to use `resample` I need to set the index to the `date` column via `df_sales.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df_sales['date']), inplace=True)`. But running `print(df_shoes['date'].resample('W'))` just gives me `DatetimeIndexResampler [freq=<Week: weekday=6>, axis=0, closed=right, label=right, convention=start, base=0]` which doesn't really help me.

It won't let me use the `sum()` function at all.

Ideally, my results would look like (or something similar where each column is a week):

```
color  |  2018-01-01  | 2018-01-08  | ... | 2018-12-24
green  |      14      |      0      | ... |     6
indigo |      9       |      3      | ... |     18
```

Any methods that would help me achieve this would be great!

Thanks

Comment: What exactly about the `resample` and pivot didn't work. Did you try `groupby` and then pivot? Please show some code

Comment: @macaw_9227 what would I `groupby`? I have edited the question to clarify things. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: `print(df_shoes['date'].resample('W'))` -- Did you forget `sum()` as mentioned right above?

Comment: @QuangHoang if I use `sum()` it gives me an error as it says I cannot perform sum on datetime

Comment: Oh, you would need to do `df_shoes.set_index('date').sales.resample('W').sum()`.

Comment: @QuangHoang ok that works, except that it gives me the sum of all colors and not each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this one more time.

convert column date to a timestamp

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date
```

then 
find locate beginning of week

```
 df['BeginWeek']=df['date']-pd.DateOffset(weekday=0,weeks=1)
```

and then pivot over the result

```
df_pivot=df.pivot_table(index='color',columns='BeginWeek',values='sales',aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)
```

Comment: That works, except that it doesn't aggregate by week. It has a column for each day.

Comment: Oh ok, what if you do df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.week

Comment: and then df_pivot=df.pivot_table(index='color',columns='date',values='sales',aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)

Comment: That also works, except that now it just counts the weeks, so that the column headers are `1, 2, .., 52` as opposed to that actually start date for that week. Would I have to do a `groupby` to get that?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so now that I understood your question, can you try:

```
# toy data frame
np.random.seed(2019)
dates = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-1-21', freq='D')
colors = np.random.randint(0,3, len(dates))
values = np.random.normal(10,20, len(dates))

df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': dates,
                   'colors': colors,
                   'values': values})    

df.groupby('colors').resample(rule='W', on='dates').values.sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
+---+--------+------------+------------+
|   | colors |   dates    |   values   |
+---+--------+------------+------------+
| 0 |      0 | 2018-01-07 | 103.963813 |
| 1 |      0 | 2018-01-14 | 52.569041  |
| 2 |      0 | 2018-01-21 | 67.987307  |
| 3 |      1 | 2018-01-07 | 2.940078   |
| 4 |      1 | 2018-01-14 | -18.655026 |
| 5 |      1 | 2018-01-21 | -7.875686  |
| 6 |      2 | 2018-01-07 | 21.254167  |
| 7 |      2 | 2018-01-14 | 8.990712   |
| 8 |      2 | 2018-01-21 | -4.180851  |
+---+--------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: This gives me the same error I was getting before: `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'`. Isn't there a need to set the `date` column to index when using `resample()`?

Comment: For upsampling, yes, for downsampling, no. I'm using pandas 0.24.2.

Comment: I am also using 0.24.2 and am still getting that error. Do you have any idea why?